# Symlink Issue - .htaccess not being read by Apache

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a folder on my server which isn’t reading the .htaccess in it. I believe the reason for this is that the folder is a symlink as the .htaccess rewrite used to work previously before the symlink was setup.

The mod rewrite should forward all requests in docs to docs/index.php so that the user can be authenticated.

My webroot is /var/www/mysite.com/

Here is my apache config:

— /etc/apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

— /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf

```
DocumentRoot /data/www/mysite.com
<Directory /data/www/mysite.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?requested_file=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

docs is a symlink to /bucket/docs:

```
docs -> /bucket/docs
```

And /bucket is a symlink to /storage:

```
bucket -> /storage/
```

I have tried to replicate the file structure on a local Vagrant setup but I have been unable to replicate the issue. If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful.